# How to implement notification system in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, notifications

I finished Ruby on Rails [tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) where I can follow other users and others may follow me like twitter. Now I wonder how to implement notification system if someone starts to follow me, for example, as in stackexchange or facebook in which come and display a notification (eg red 1). How to go about it? Are there any examples of ready solutions you or MVC?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ruby -Rails notification system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552834/rails-notification-system)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd add a `before_filter` to relevant controller actions that checks for new followers in the database and sets `flash[:notice]` to something useful like 'X new followers' and links to your followers page. There's a quick overview of how flash works in the docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html

Comment: You can do a demonstration of how before_filter could look like? Sorry for my indolence.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of using filters. Here's one: http://rails.nuvvo.com/lesson/6373-action-controller-filters

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at those 2 railscasts:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/407-activity-feed-from-scratch
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity.

Comment: The above two railscasts are for implementing activity feed but not for notificatoin system. Implementing facebook news feed and implementing facebook notification system both different.